# How does one mark a test as anything like "inconclusive" in Google Test?

Tags: c++, googletest

We have a test that fails if the test suite is not run with administrator rights. This is expected behavior. However, we want to return something other than success from the test suite so that someone remembers to go back and try the tests again as admin.

Is there a way to tell Google Test that the test hasn't failed, but hasn't really succeeded either?

Comment: I'm of the habit of avoiding this problem by any means necessary.

Comment: @Joshua: Me too. Unfortunately the code under test is supposed to load a driver into the Kernel. Hard to test that without admin :)

Comment: If getting root is a fixture, imagine (or better yet, make) the fixture as RAII. If the fixture fails to set up (acquire) the test is futile and should abort with error. It's an error of a different dimension, like a function returning an error flag but that can also throw.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: But I don't want it to be an error. (I guess I'm used to NUnit where you have three possible test states)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think there is a way to tell GoogleTest that a test has not failed, but has not passed either.

That said, the closest is probably EXPECT, a non-fatal assertion: http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_Primer#Assertions

The test will fail, but execution of the test function will continue, which seems to be what you want.

Answer (score 2):

What I'd do is separate out the component into two pieces (two projects). The project that has the kernel driver requires admin to test, and the other project mocks it for test purposes so the test doesn't fail.